# В чем разница между int и int ^?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

В чем разница между `int` и `int ^`?
на примере инициализации массива (обе компилируются без ошибок):

```
array<int> ^arr = gcnew array<int>(3) { 1, 2, 3 };
array<int ^> ^arr2 = gcnew array<int ^>(3) { 1, 2, 3 };
```

В первом случае мы объявляем массив типа `int` и инициализируем его `int` значениями. Почему тогда во втором случае мы объявляем массив типа `int ^`, а инициализируем его теми же значениями `int`? Дескриптор разве не указатель? Его разименовывать не надо?

Comment: какой тип у arr и arr2?

Comment: дополнил объявлением

Comment: `^`- [указатель](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2017)  на управляемые объекты.

Comment: Во втором случае, насколько я понимаю, происходит [autoboxing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).